# How to import 2 separate files with the same name in the same python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say that I have the following files with given paths:

```
/home/project/folder1/common.py
/home/project/folder2/common.py
```

So, these files have the same name but they are in different folders.

And I need to import both of these files in the same python script that is located in a separate path, as following:

```
/home/project/folder3/abc.py
```

If it was only 1 file I needed to import, I could do the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'/home/project/folder1')
import common as c
```

And then I could access e.g. constants from `/home/project/folder1/common.py` as `c.MY_CONSTANT`.

But how can I import both `/home/project/folder1/common.py` and `/home/project/folder1/common.py` in the file `/home/project/folder3/abc.py` ?

Please note that constants that I would like to access from `abc.py` may have the same names. With other words, `MY_CONSTANT` may exist in both `common.py` files.

What I would like to achieve is the following (though I know that this is wrong syntax in Python):

```
import /home/project/folder1/common as c1
import /home/project/folder2/common as c2
```

... so that I can access both files with `c1.` and `c2.`.

So, how can I import both files in the same Python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit odd calling both files `common.py`, by their naming and placement they're anything but common :). But here you go. You need to make your `abc.py` script "see" your top-level project directory. Since it is in `/home`, adding the path to your home directory achieves that.

```py
   import sys
   sys.path.append(r"/home")

   from project.folder1 import common as c1
   from project.folder2 import common as c2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Really appreciated. Yes, it looks quite odd in the example but there is a reason behind it, which is a bit long to describe here. :)